# Printing Numbers in X Shape pattern in python in increasing to decreasing order

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I am solving a pattern problem in python, i need to  print a pattern in such a way it consists of `X` and the numbers are filled first in increasing order and then after reaching mid number, they go to decreasing order,

basically i did what, i find out the area where the `X` will display.,and fill the remaining matrix with blank spaces..,

but it is not according to my pattern..

[Output Pattern image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RDIV.png)

here is my approach:

```
n=int(input("Enter total rows"))
#n=5
for rows in range(n):
  for cols in range(n):
    if((rows == cols) or (rows+cols)==n-1 ):
      print(rows,end="")
    else:
      print(" ",end="")
  print()
```

what i am trying to do is:
`left diagonal and Right diagonal numbers` :`0 1 2 1 0`
but what i am getting is:
`left diagonal and Right diagonal numbers` :`0 1 2 3 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the `min(rows, n - rows - 1)` instead of `rows` -

```
n = 5
for rows in range(n):
  for cols in range(n):
    if((rows == cols) or (rows+cols)==n-1 ):
      print(min(rows, n - rows - 1),end="")
    else:
      print(" ",end="")
  print()
```

**Output:**

```
0   0
 1 1 
  2  
 1 1 
0   0
```

For `n = 7` -

```
0     0
 1   1 
  2 2  
   3   
  2 2  
 1   1 
0     0
```

For `n = 6` -

```
0    0
 1  1 
  22  
  22  
 1  1 
0    0
```

Comment: ok..it is working for the given test case.. but for other numbers like 5 or 6, etc. it is forming something different patter..

Comment: It's returning correct pattern for all odd numbers. What's the expected output for even numbers. e.g. 4/6?

Comment: ok..yeah..got it,, u were right..this question was only for odd numbers..it was drawn on the book..but had no solution.., so i guess.,,this pattern is only possible with odd number..btw thanks ..

Comment: yes..i want to..but i need more reputation to approve the answer...its the first day..

Answer (score 0):

This is a longer alternative, but it does work. However you will run into a weird issue when entering an even number.

```py
n = int(input("Enter Total Rows: "))

matrix = []

# Append each row and column to the matrix.
for rows in range(n):
  row = []
  for cols in range(n):
    row.append(" ")

  matrix.append(row)

for i in range(n):
  if i > n/2:  # After we reach the center, start to subtract numbers instead of adding
    matrix[i][i] = abs(i - (n - 1))  # Abs is so we can invert the negative number to a positive
  else:
    matrix[i][i] = i

  if i > n/2:  # Ditto, but now instead of top left to bottom right, it goes top right to bottom left
    matrix[i][n - (i + 1)] = abs(i - (n - 1))
  else:
    matrix[i][n - (i + 1)] = i

# Print each row of the matrix
for i in range(len(matrix)):
  print(*matrix[i])
```

Comment: Yes..i see it is working fine with odd numbers..,anyways thankyou.. i need to figure out that actually is happening here.

Comment: Here, ill add comments to make it easier.